# Can Cartodb map show only United States?

Tags: carto

I have made my map with cartodb, showing where certain work is going on throughout the United States. I want to send it out, but would prefer the map to only show the United States--whereas now it shows Canada and Mexico as well. I am using the free cartodb.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if you can remove countries from the CartoDB map server, then no. But you can change your zoom level of where the map starts. When you do that you will be provided a new share link. You will want to play with the settings before to send out the final shared link.